# Printing PDF/Doc/Docx from Mac OS X application?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there any way to print .doc, .docx, .pdf files without opening a native application in Cocoa,

Is there any way to invoke NSPrintPanel from my application which will probably invoke a print 
dialog with given file.

I am new to COCOA programming, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Printing requires a view. If I remember correctly, the default behavior is to print the content view of the main window.

So, the easiest way is to make your main window's only view (within the content view) either a PDFView or an NSTextView, into which you've loaded the contents of the PDF or Word file.

If you want to have other views, then you need to customize your printing, in which case I direct you to [the Printing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/).

Comment: Hi Peter, I have customized QLPreview and displaying the documents in it, in this specific case whenever I say Print, it displays the correct first page in PrintPreview Panel but since other pages are not visible those number of pages kept blank by PrintpreviewPanel

Comment: @AnupRojekar: It would probably be easier to just use PDFView or NSTextView than to twist QLPreviewView into this shape. As you say, a preview view only displays some section of the document at a time; it provides no way to ensure that it shows the whole document. (And for PDFs, you truly can't: If it's anything like QLPreviewPanel, a QLPreviewView always displays PDFs one page at a time, no matter how tall you make it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter for your answer, but had a problem while displaying Doc/Docx files in the NSTextView, Since integrity of the document gets lost, because of that I have used QLPreview.